# Compile error with GDAL on MacOSX

Tags: gdal

I've been trying to install the GDAL Python package on my MacOS Mojave 10.14.1.

I ran the following:

```
brew install gdal
```

This works fine, though I do get this warning (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/34783). I read that it could be safely ignored, though when I try to run:

```
pip install GDAL
```

I get the following error log here (https://pastebin.com/nsfj86Jg):

The important bit is that it doesn't appear able to locate standard C++ include files, resulting in the build failure.

```
warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-std=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3096:10: fatal error: 'stdexcept' file not found
#include <stdexcept>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm not sure how to specify the compiler to use from `pip`, I assume it has to be done elsewhere, or that I'm missing something else completely.

Answer (score 1):

You can get GDAL with python bindings and command line utilities from NextGIS Installer (http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/). Just uncheck everything except gdal utilities in installer. Also, I recommend to uninstall GDAL from brew, because conflicts may occur.

[image]

In this case no compilation needed.

Otherwise you will need to install the XCode or gcc.